# Power Bi Custom Column funtion

Tags: powerbi

In MQuery, I'm trying to create a custom column.  If another column has a value of 1 through 5 then the value in new column will be some text.  It's given me a Token Else expected error.

```
=if[#"Chair Independence Level"] = "1" then "Same Product Line" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= "2" then "Different Product Line" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= "3" then "Different Business Area" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= "4" then "Different Sector" 
else if [#"Chair Independence Level"]= "5" then "Not an Employee"
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem or what I should change my code to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IF condition in Power query needs to be capped off with an ELSE statement. Just add the ELSE and you should be good to go:

```
=if[#"Chair Independence Level"] = "1" then "Same Product Line" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= "2" then "Different Product Line" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= "3" then "Different Business Area" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= "4" then "Different Sector" 
else if [#"Chair Independence Level"]= "5" then "Not an Employee"
else "NA"
```

If the #"Chair Independence Level" field is numeric, then:

```
=if[#"Chair Independence Level"] = 1 then "Same Product Line" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= 2 then "Different Product Line" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= 3 then "Different Business Area" 
else if[#"Chair Independence Level"]= 4 then "Different Sector" 
else if [#"Chair Independence Level"]= 5 then "Not an Employee"
else "NA"
```

Comment: thank you!!! the error went away.  but I got NA for all the rows.  I checked the "Chair Independence Level" column and all the data is 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.  with no spaces before or after.

Comment: Is the field in numeric format? You can try removing the quotes from the numbers

Comment: The "Chair Independence Level" field is but the new column is text.

Comment: If the field is numeric, then you should not use the quotes...i will add an edit to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are working on the mQuery side of powerby so no DAX.

You are missing your last else statement:

```
else if [#"Chair Independence Level"]= "5" then "Not an Employee" ELSE "the other"
```